# Como utilizar brackpoint con phpstorm de jetbrain

Tags: php, depuración

Estimado colegas

Estoy utilizando phpstorm para mis desarrollos y quisiera saber como puedo configurar la depuracion para poder utilizar puntos de quiebre, algo similar a lo que se puede hacer con visual studio, nose si es posible con phpstorm por eso pido su ayudar

Saludos

Comment: Hola Pablo. Has mirado la documentacion del programa para ver si admite breakpoints?

Comment: Hola amigo, si por lo que pude leer si lo admite, pero me complique en la configuracion de este, tal vez alguien me pueda ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Debes instalar el componente de xDebugger en tu php y configurar phpstorm para que este a la escucha de conexiones remotas. Ademas deberás instalar algun componente en tu navegador tipo xdebug helper (chrome) y activarlo cada vez que quieras que el navegador lance una interrupción al IDE.

documentación:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide

Comment: Lo probare y le comento Gracias!